# Questions Regarding Part II form W-9S

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am on F-1 Visa and my school told me that I can get 1098 T for tuition waiver if I submit form W-9S. I have a question regarding Part II of form [W-9S](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9s.pdf)

[image]

My Question :

Since I haven't taken any student loan and I have paid the fees using my credit card, I am wondering is its mandatory for me to sign Part II of the form? I am confused since paying via credit card is also a type of loan only.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to fill out Part II.

The W-9S form is used for two different purposes: Your school can use it to obtain your taxpayer identification number (TIN) to issue you a 1098-T (tuition statement), and a student loan lender can use it to obtain your TIN to issue you a 1098-E (student loan interest statement).

Since your school gave the form to you, and you aren't getting a student loan from your school, you don't need to fill out Part II.  A credit card does not count as a student loan in this case.  If you take out a student loan in the future, your lender will give you this form and have you fill out Part II, which certifies that you will only use the funds for your education, making the interest deductible.